# How to set multple resources in phalcon api rest?

Tags: php, phalcon

i just followed this docs [api rest phalcon](http://docs.phalconphp.com/es/latest/reference/tutorial-rest.html) and it worked!, but i don't know how to properly set more resources like robots in the example, if i have 10 resources i don't like to have them in the same file.

using router?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If by resources you mean models and if it works as is, you can simply create more models in `my-rest-api/models/` directory. Normally you'd need to configure an autoloader, but micro apps probably know where to get models from.

If you are asking how to make your app better organised you probably need to move away from the micro app and take advantage of the MVC pattern. If in the example you worked with a single model and all related logic was handled in a single file, with MVC all logic is organised into controllers. Normally single controller handles logic related to a single model or models related to it. The [official tutorial](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial.html#creating-a-project) explores this in depth with further references.

**Edit:**

And as Julian himself pointed out `Phalcon\Mvc\Micro\Collection` is [another approach](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Micro_Collection.html) for micro apps.

Comment: mmmm, but in that case is the app api rest?

Comment: Go back and do some learning! Whether it acts as a REST API depends on how you implement it. The tutorial covers the basics of it, to add it elements of a REST API you'll need to know how to configure routing, how to disable standard views and return JSON. There are plenty of information around, but if you are starting to learn it would be better to go example by example and then start combining them together.

Comment: Alternatively you can read [this](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/32/using-controllers-in-a-micro-application), there are suggestions on how to use controllers in a micro app, but this smells like a dirty hack.

Comment: thanks man!, i solved it using microcollectios and mvc, and the views disabled of course dont need them, http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Micro_Collection.html,

Comment: Yep, thats the best solution for doing it the micro-app fashion.